# Integer quadratic representation subject to discriminant minimization algorithm

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, computability-theory, computational-number-theory

Let $f(x)=ax^2+bx+c$ and $f(x)=n$. Is there an algorithm to choose $a,b,c$ such that the discriminant is minimized? Where $a,b,c,n,x$ are all integers.

More concretely, is there an algorithm to find $a,b,c$ in $f(x)=ax^2+bx+c=n$ such that:

1. $a,c > 0$
2. $|x| > 1$
3. $\gcd(a,b,c)=1$
4. $d=\min\{|b^2-4ac|\}$ where d is the discriminant of $f$.

Comment: Take $a=c=0$, $b=1$, then $d=1$, and every $n$ is represented.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I mean, sure, but then $f(x)$ is not a degree 2 polynomial....the underlying assumption being that $a\not=0$. The discriminant of a degree $1$ polynomial is not all that interesting.

Comment: $a = n - 1$, $c = 0$, $b = 1$. Then $x = 1$, $d = 1$.

Comment: @DenisShatrov Thank you. I just realized I missed some conditions. I have updated the question appropriately.

Comment: I'm afraid you still haven't ruled out some answers you won't like. $f(x)=nx^2+2nx+n$ has $f(0)=n$ and discriminant $(2n)^2-4nn=0$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thank you. I did not think it would be this difficult to specify this. wow. Can I just say, trivial answers aside? The suspects being $\{0,1,n\}$ in some combination distributed among $a,b,c,x$.

Comment: Maybe, but I think you don't want to rule out things like $f(x)=x^2+3x+2$, $f(0)=2$, discriminant $1$, or $f(x)=x^2+x+1$, $f(1)=3$, discriminant $-3$, just because they use zero and/or one and/or $n$. You need to pin down what's trivial, and what isn't. Is $f(x)=2x^2+4x+2$, $f(2)=18$, discriminant zero, trivial?

Comment: @GerryMyerson I think I got it right this time.

Comment: Are $n,x$ constant, or part of the optimization?

Comment: I'm not sure why you want $c>0$ (though I can see why you want $c\ne0$). E.g., $11$ is represented by $x^2+x-1$ with discriminant $5$ (although I suppose you can use $x^2+3x+1$ instead). Anyway, I'm almost convinced now that one can always find a representation by a quadratic with discriminant $1$. E.g., take $n=1000$. Then $f(x)=141x^2-95x+16$ has $f(3)=1000$ and discriminant $1$.

Comment: By the way, it is more common to ask about representation by binary quadratic *forms* $f(x,y)=ax^2+bxy+cy^2=n$ than to ask about representation by a one-variable polynomial. There is a large literature about the representation by binary quadratic forms, there are many known results, and many hard problems.

Answer (score 0):

Given $n$, we wish to find $a,b,c,x$ such that $a,b,c$ satisfy the given conditions, $b^2-4ac=1$, and $ax^2+bx+c=n$.

Given $a,b,c$, for $ax^2+bx+c=n$ to have an integer solution we need $b^2-4a(c-n)$ to be a square. This is $b^2-4ac+4an$. Now assume $b^2-4ac=1$. Then we want $1+4an$ to be a square. Since $1$ is a quadratic residue modulo $4n$, this can always be achieved; for any $n$, we can find $a,r$ such that $1+4an=r^2$.

Now we have $a$, but we still need $b^2-4ac=1$, that is, we need $1+4ac$ to be a square. But $1$ is a quadratic residue modulo $4a$, so we can find $c$ such that $1+4ac=b^2$ for some $b$. We now have $a,b,c$ such that $b^2-4ac=1$, and $ax^2+bx+c=n$.

Only, I'm not seeing how we know $x$ is an integer. It follows from the above that it's rational, and when I did the calculations for $n=1000$ it gave me $x=3$, but just at the moment I don't see the justification for asserting that $x$ is guaranteed to be an integer, not just a rational. So, consider this to be work-in-progress.

Comment: Simply $a=n+1$, $b=-2n-1$, $c=n$ and $x=0$ does the trick.

Comment: @Joachim, yes, that's similar to the comment Denis Shatrov left a few days ago, then OP indicated that he meant to rule out such answers. But if $n$ is prime, then my construction only leads to quadratics with leading coefficient $n\pm1$.

Comment: I see (although the above still doesn't seem to be ruled out in the current wording). I guess there are just too many degrees of freedom allowed in order to make this an interesting problem.

Comment: @JoachimKönig Thank you for the input. I think, requiring, $|x|>1$ solves this trivial answer.

Comment: But you can just substitute, say, $x-2$ for $x$, and get a quadratic with the same discriminant, but with $f(2)=n$. The substitution doesn't affect the leading coefficient, $a$, which will still be $n+1$.